# Access classMethods from getterMethods in Sequelize.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I'm having trouble accessing a classMethod from within a getterMethod in a Sequelize model.

This is my model so far:

```
module.exports = db.define('user', {
    email: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    password: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    avatar: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
    },
}, {
    getterMethods: {
        avatarComplete: function() {
            return getUploadPath(this.avatar);
        }
    },
    classMethods: {
        getUploadPath: (_path) => {
            return env.UPLOAD_PATH + _path;
        }
    }
});
```

Within the getterMethods I have a `avatarComplete` method that is trying to access a `classMethod` of the same Sequelize model.

The reason why I decided to have a separate classMethod is because sometimes I need to invoke the `getUploadPath` method by itself.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: what was an error?

Comment: `getUploadPath` is undefined